# How to mount/resize/modify LVM partition in KVM qcow2 or raw images?

Tags: lvm, kvm-virtualization, qcow2

I have KVM qcow2 and raw images. Virtual machines are partitioned with LVM. Now I want to resize the root partition of a few machines so I guess I have to do this from the host. 
My question is: how can I do this with raw images or qcow2 images ?

I'm a little bit confused by KVM+LVM complexity.

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, LVM images inside qcow2 files is a mess. I personally try to avoid them, as multiple layers of LVM can cause shocking headaches.

But you will find the answer here:

[Mount LVM within a disk image](https://serverfault.com/questions/162436/mount-lvm-within-a-disk-image)

Good luck!

Comment: Well I read that qcow2 was one good option to backup VM without stopping them, and LVM may be usefull for resizing partitions.

Comment: What I do is that I create an LVM volume in the Dom0, then use it as a block device HDD for the domU. This way I can take an LVM snapshot and do backup on it. I can still resize the last partition, if needed. And as I typically only have two partitions for the virtual host (swap and /) that is no problem.

Comment: then can you distribute VMs to others ? Can you do live migrations of VMs if your dom0/host is crowded ?

Comment: I have not used live migrations other than for a few POC. I don't have need for them in my environment.